# Restoring database backup causes bad characters

Tags: mysql, linux

Is it possible that simply using `mysql -h [IP] -u root -p [DATABASE] < [FILE].sql` to restore a database would cause Spanish characters to lose their "Spanish" and show up all funky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://labs.leftcolumn.net/2009/09/how-to-prevent-weird-characters-after-mysql-export-and-import/):

> The issue is essentially tied up with a mismatch between default
>   collation in MySQL and the collation / character sets specified in the
>   .sql file. To fix the issue, make sure they all match. If you’re using
>   MySQL 4+, the default collation is probably UTF-8, so just make sure
>   that the file has a default colltion set too. Putting the following
>   line at the top of the .sql seems to do the trick:
>
> ```
> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
> ```
>
> The reason seems to be with the importer: even though there is a
>   default collation set on the database and on the tables, if there’s no
>   default for the whole file each insert gets misinterpreted as a UTF-8
>   table that must be encapsulated in as latin1. Also check that the
>   table creation statements in the .sql file are UTF-8 too, like this:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `wp_comments` (
> ...
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

Comment: UTF8 was specified in PHPMyAdmin when I imported the file.  The tables are also UTF 8.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a latin1 vs utf8 mismatch. The old database may have been dumped in one encoding and the new database created with a different default encoding. Try using the `--default-character-set=utf8` flag or replace utf8 with latin1 is that doesn't work.